# How can I configure the fonts and colors in the Pycharm "Find" tab

Tags: pycharm

So, I am currently using Pycharm as my IDE, and it is mostly working great. There is one persistent problem, however, which is that I have been utterly unable to get search results in the "Find" tab (alt+3) formatted. Using the Darcula editor scheme, I wind up with a lot of extremely difficult to read results, with dark text on a dark background, such as the one below. So far I've been completely unable to figure out what part of the settings is responsible for formatting these results. Does anyone have any advice on how I can change these font colors?

[image: What my Find in Path results look like]

Comment: Try resetting you Editor color scheme as well as GUI Theme -- chose light ones (Default, for example); restart IDE; change them both to Darcula. Usually helps in this kind of situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow your colours got mixed up between light and dark themes. I suggest resetting both of your editor colour scheme and GUI theme:

- Editor color scheme: `Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Editor | Colors & Fonts`
- GUI Theme: `Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Appearance & Behavior | Appearance`

The idea is:

- choose light ones for both (e.g. "Default" & "IntelliJ" accordingly)
- restart IDE
- change them both back to Darcula

Usually this helps on this kind of situations.